# PATCH request on a login attempt

Tags: tls, authentication, rest, web-authentication

I have a problem deciding what is the most secure method to send a login request with a username and password strings, I understood that PATCH is less secure than PUT while both are less secure than POST, would it be more sensible then to use POST?

However their purposes are quite different, I thought that PATCH was what I needed because it finds the needed user and creates a session for it.

Comment: *"I understood that PATCH is less secure than PUT while both are less secure than POST,"* - In my opinion none of these methods are more or less secure than the other, so please provide the details on how you came up with this grading. As for choosing PATCH request for login - I cannot follow your arguments here on why this should be the right method and it is a unconventional choice. There is no "resource" involved here to patch/update.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well obviously the "User" in this case is the resource and I want to update it's session.

Comment: "I understood that PATCH is less secure than PUT while both are less secure than POST" Please elaborate on why you think that.

Comment: " I thought that PATCH was what I needed" -- why do you think that?

Comment: @JanSafronov: You say it is obvious? Well... 1) It is obvious that user can have many devices. 2) It is obvious that user can have many browsers on each device. 3) It is obvious the for each browser user can use many profiles with independent sessions. 4) It is obvious that so many sessions cannot be represented by a single resource. 5) It is obvious that there are many different approaches to design API, without using any "resouce" concept.

Answer (score 2):

As Steffen Ullrich pointed in comments, neither of these methods is more or less secure, they aren't related to security at all, they are part of RESTful API architectural style. There are several common HTTP verbs used in RESTful API ([reference](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/)):

| Name | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| GET | used to retrieve resource |
| POST | used to create resource |
| PUT | used to fully update resource |
| PATCH | used partially update resource |
| DELETE | used to delete resource |

In login process you do not update any resource, you create new resource (session). Using GET, PUT, PATCH or DELETE for this operation is RESTful API guidelines violation.

> Well obviously the "User" in this case is the resource

it is not correct, User is not a resource here, authenticated session is. And you create it with POST method.